# How to show mouse coordinates over canvas using pure javascript in tooltip form?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So its about html5 canvas. So I want to see something like `x:11, y:33` in form of tooltip near to mouse when mouse is on canvas like [image]... mouse moves tooltip moves with it showing coordinates. How to do such thing with javascript and html 5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var canvas = $('#canvas').get(0);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var w = h = canvas.width = canvas.height = 300;

  ctx.fillStyle = '#0099f9';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    var str = 'X : ' + x + ', ' + 'Y : ' + y;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#0099f9';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ddd';
    ctx.fillRect(x + 10, y + 10, 80, 25);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.font = 'bold 20px verdana';
    ctx.fillText(str, x + 20, y + 30, 60);

  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

### [A simple Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusxr69n/)

Comment: how to use this script for image which drawn in canvas?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an HTML5 canvas tooltip that will do this.  It's written with the Processing.js library for a visualization web-app I'm writing, but it can be used from pure javascript also.  You can download the code with example web page from [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/1205509).  You can read about and see a live example, which happens to show the mouse coordinates, [here](http://bayesianconspiracy.blogspot.com/2011/09/tooltip-class-for-html5-canvas-written.html).